# How get the percentage of totals for each count after a groupBy in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

Given the following DataFrame:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([['a',1],['b', 2],['a', 3]], ['category', 'value'])
df.show()


+--------+-----+
|category|value|
+--------+-----+
|       a|    1|
|       b|    2|
|       a|    3|
+--------+-----+
```

I want to count the number of items in each category and provide a percentage of total for each count, like so

```
+--------+-----+----------+
|category|count|percentage|
+--------+-----+----------+
|       b|    1|     0.333|
|       a|    2|     0.667|
+--------+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `groupby` and aggregate with `agg`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupby('category').agg(F.count('value') / df.count()).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+------------------+
|category|(count(value) / 3)|
+--------+------------------+
|       b|0.3333333333333333|
|       a|0.6666666666666666|
+--------+------------------+
```

To make it nicer you can use:

```
df.groupby('category').agg(
    (
        F.round(F.count('value') / df.count(), 2)
    ).alias('ratio')
).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----+
|category|ratio|
+--------+-----+
|       b| 0.33|
|       a| 0.67|
+--------+-----+
```

You can also use SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT category, COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df) AS ratio
    FROM df
    GROUP BY category
    """
).show()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain the count and percentage/ratio of totals with the following

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df.groupBy('category').count()\
  .withColumn('percentage', f.round(f.col('count') / f.sum('count')\
  .over(Window.partitionBy()),3)).show()

+--------+-----+----------+
|category|count|percentage|
+--------+-----+----------+
|       b|    1|     0.333|
|       a|    2|     0.667|
+--------+-----+----------+
```

The previous statement can be divided in steps. `df.groupBy('category').count()`  produces the `count`:

```
+--------+-----+
|category|count|
+--------+-----+
|       b|    1|
|       a|    2|
+--------+-----+
```

then by applying window functions we can obtain the total count on each row:

```
df.groupBy('category').count().withColumn('total', f.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy())).show()

+--------+-----+-----+
|category|count|total|
+--------+-----+-----+
|       b|    1|    3|
|       a|    2|    3|
+--------+-----+-----+
```

where the `total` column is calculated by adding together all the counts in the partition (a single partition that includes all rows).

Once we have `count`  and `total`  for each row we can calculate the ratio:

```
df.groupBy('category')\
  .count()\
  .withColumn('total', f.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy()))\
  .withColumn('percentage',f.col('count')/f.col('total'))\
  .show()

+--------+-----+-----+------------------+
|category|count|total|        percentage|
+--------+-----+-----+------------------+
|       b|    1|    3|0.3333333333333333|
|       a|    2|    3|0.6666666666666666|
+--------+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: how would you do this in spark SQL.   I can't figure out a way to do the empty partition by in plain spark sql