# Calculating percentage of total count for groupBy using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code in pyspark, resulting in a table showing me the different values for a column and their counts. I want to have another column showing what percentage of the total count does each row represent. How do I do that?

```
difrgns = (df1
           .groupBy("column_name")
           .count()
           .sort(desc("count"))
           .show())
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a recent self-answered question that should work for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264844/how-get-the-percentage-of-totals-for-each-count-after-a-groupby-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

An example as an alternative if not comfortable with Windowing as the comment alludes to and is the better way to go:

```
# Running in Databricks, not all stuff required
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
#from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = [("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
        ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

someschema = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(c1=x[0], c2=x[1], val1=int(x[2]), val2=int(x[3])))

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(someschema)

tot = df.count()

df.groupBy("c1") \
  .count() \
  .withColumnRenamed('count', 'cnt_per_group') \
  .withColumn('perc_of_count_total', (F.col('cnt_per_group') / tot) * 100 ) \
  .show()
```

returns:

```
 +---+-------------+-------------------+
| c1|cnt_per_group|perc_of_count_total|
+---+-------------+-------------------+
|  E|            1| 16.666666666666664|
|  B|            1| 16.666666666666664|
|  D|            1| 16.666666666666664|
|  C|            1| 16.666666666666664|
|  A|            2|  33.33333333333333|
+---+-------------+-------------------+
```

I focus on Scala and it seems easier with that. That said, the suggested solution via the comments uses Window which is what I would do in Scala with over().

Comment: I think you need to broadcast your `tot` variable first.

Comment: Could but not compulsory as far as I can see in practice. Errors wouldhave been noted.

Answer (score 7):

When `df` itself is a more complex transformation chain and running it twice -- first to compute the total count and then to group and compute percentages -- is too expensive, it's possible to leverage a window function to achieve similar results.  Here's a more generalized code (extending [bluephantom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6933993/thebluephantom)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285108/384803)) that could be used with a number of group-by dimensions:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data = [("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
        ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

someschema = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(c1=x[0], c2=x[1], val1=int(x[2]), val2=int(x[3])))

df = (sqlContext.createDataFrame(someschema)
      .withColumn('total_count', count('*').over(Window.partitionBy(<your N-1 dimensions here>)))
     .groupBy(<your N dimensions here>)
       .agg((count('*')/first(col('total_count'))).alias('percent_total'))
)

df.show()
```

Comment: Using a window function is an interesting idea, but are you sure your example code is correct? I tried running it with `<your dimensions here>` set to `"c1"` and every value of `c1` came back with a `percent_total` of `1.0`.

Comment: @NickChammas: yes, the template code is correct, but you have to be careful with dimensions: total count is done at a different level than groupby, i.e. if group by is done with N dimensions, then the window function has to be partitioned by N-1 dimensions.  For OP's example in particular if groupBy('c1'), then use Window.partitionBy() with no arguments.

Comment: how would you do the partitionBy with no arguments using regular spark SQL?

Comment: @Dalupus: try constructing a PySpark query above and then run "explain" on it.  This should give you the SQL equivalent if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

You can `groupby` and aggregate with `agg`. For example, for the following DataFrame:

```
+--------+-----+
|category|value|
+--------+-----+
|       a|    1|
|       b|    2|
|       a|    3|
+--------+-----+
```

You can use:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.groupby('category').agg(
    (F.count('value')).alias('count'),
    (F.count('value') / df.count()).alias('percentage')
).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+-----+------------------+
|category|count|        percentage|
+--------+-----+------------------+
|       b|    1|0.3333333333333333|
|       a|    2|0.6666666666666666|
+--------+-----+------------------+
```

Alternatively, you can use SQL:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT category,
           COUNT(*) AS count,
           COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df) AS ratio
    FROM df
    GROUP BY category
    """
).show()
```

Answer (score 5):

More "beatified" output, eliminating the excess decimals and sort it

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
count_cl = data_fr.count()

data_fr \
.groupBy('col_name') \
.count() \
.withColumn('%', func.round((func.col('count')/count_cl)*100,2)) \
.orderBy('count', ascending=False) \
.show(4, False)
```

```html
    +--------------+-----+----+
    | col_name     |count|   %|
    +--------------------+----+
    |      C.LQQQQ |30957|8.91|
    |      C.LQQQQ |29688|8.54|
    |      C-LQQQQ |29625|8.52|
    |       CLQQQQ |29342|8.44|    
    +--------------------+----+
```

Comment: What is `count_c1` here?