# Compute proportion of values within groups

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to calculate the proportion of a specific value occurring in a specific column within subgroups.

Sample dataframe

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
    'letter': ['L', 'A', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'L']
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.show()
```

I tried to rely on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264844/how-get-the-percentage-of-totals-for-each-count-after-a-groupby-in-pyspark) answer but with the following code

```
df\
    .groupby('id')\
    .agg((count(col('letter') == 'L') / count(col('letter'))).alias('prop'))\
    .show()
```

I obtained a column full of `1.0`, even when I changed `'L'` to `'A'`.

My desired output is, for each group, the proportion of `'L'` values within the group:

```
+---+--------+
| id|    prop|
+---+--------+
|  1|    0.75|
|  2|     1.0|
|  3| 0.66667|
+---+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you count, you need to mask the non-L letters with nulls using `when`:

```
df\
    .groupby('id')\
    .agg((count(when(col('letter') == 'L', 1)) / count(col('letter'))).alias('prop'))\
    .show()
```

Note that `count` will only count non-null entries. It does not only count `true` entries, as you had expected in your code. Your code is more suitable if you're using [`count_if`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#count_if) from Spark SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum` with `when` instead to count the occurrences of `L`:

```
df.groupby('id')\
  .agg((F.sum(F.when(F.col('letter') == 'L', 1)) / F.count(F.col('letter'))).alias('prop'))\
  .show()
```

This will give you the proportion only in non-null values. If you want to calculate on all rows, divide by `count("*")`instead of `count(col('letter'))`.